# How can use JAVA 8 filter for following code

Tags: java, java-8

```
String url="/acct/StatsClientListService?clientType=AllClient";
List<String> urlQueryParams =new ArrayList<String>();
String clientType =null;
String urlBool = null;
List<String> urlSplit = Pattern.compile("\\?").splitAsStream(url).collect(Collectors.toList());
//condition based results
if(urlSplit.size() == 2){
    urlQueryParams=Pattern.compile("&").splitAsStream(urlSplit.get(1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    if(urlQueryParams.size() == 2 ){
        clientType = urlQueryParams.get(0).split("=")[1];
        urlBool = urlQueryParams.get(0).split("=")[1];
        System.out.println("clientType --  "+clientType + "   urlBool ---- "+urlBool);
    }
    else{
        clientType = urlQueryParams.get(0).split("=")[1];
        System.out.println("clientType --  "+clientType);
    }
}
else{
    System.out.println("url without params");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: why do you need a filter for that? what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to use java-8 feature, there is dynamic  url which I want to split that may contains none, 1 and 2 query parameters and setting up into variables. how can I use java-8 filters and optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following snippet might be a point to start with.

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/acct/StatsClientListService"
        + "?clientType=AllClient&something=interesting");
Stream.of(url.getQuery().split("&"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                s -> s.replaceFirst("^(.*)=.*", "$1"), 
                s -> s.replaceFirst("^.*=(.*)", "$1")))
        .forEach((k, v) -> 
                System.out.printf("param: %s  value: %s%n", k, v)
        );
```

**output**

```
param: clientType  value: AllClient
param: something  value: interesting
```

**edit** If the URL string contain only the path and (optional) the query you might start with this snippet.

```
String urlString = "/acct/StatsClientListService"
        + "?clientType=AllClient&something=interesting";
if (urlString.contains("?")) {
    String query = urlString.substring(urlString.indexOf("?") + 1);
    Stream.of(query.split("&"))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                s -> s.replaceFirst("^(.*)=.*", "$1"),
                s -> s.replaceFirst("^.*=(.*)", "$1")))
        .forEach((k, v)
                -> System.out.printf("param: %s  value: %s%n", k, v)
        );
}
```

**output**

```
param: clientType  value: AllClient
param: something  value: interesting
```

**note** Additional checks for the `urlString` are necessary. Depending on which values are possible.

Comment: Thanks, but this url is dynamic which may contains  Query String or may not. In case of not containing query string getting nullPointerException.

Comment: that's why in my snippet code I am checking condition with size then splitting further.

Comment: The snippets is not meant as a complete solution. See `might be a point to start with`. It demonstrate the splitting of the query parameter. To place a simple `if (url.getQuery() == null) ...` before executing it should be straight forward.

Comment: Url which I am getting is not complete Url(I mean not starting with "http://example ....."), So can't use URL object and their methods.

Comment: @user2902870 I added another example for an URL string without the host part. As you still did not phrase a question, beside the title of your post it's hard to guess what you want to achieve. My snippets are more or less incomplete guess-work. ;-)

Comment: thanks for the help :) your solution works for me